# How do get PlotAreaPoint with multi touch events in core plot on ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I'm using the CPPlotSpaceDelegate protocol to receive touches on iOS and following methods after setting the delegate for my defaultPlotSpace:

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event 
          atPoint:(CGPoint)point{

}

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{

   NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
   UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   UITouch *touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];

   /*
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space;
    CPTScatterPlot *scatterPlot = [[[plotSpace graph] allPlots] objectAtIndex:0]; 
    CGPoint plotAreaPoint = [[plotSpace graph] convertPoint:point toLayer:scatterPlot];
    NSLog(@"PlotAreaPoint : %.1f, %.1f", plotAreaPoint.x, plotAreaPoint.y);
   */

}
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
}
```

How can i get 'PlotAreaPoint' from multiple touches? Anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The hosting view will ignore multi-touch events except for pinch gestures. Only events with a single touch will be passed to the graph and then on to the plots and plot space.

If you need to capture multi-touch events this way, you can change the `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` method in `CPTGraphHostingView` to pass along the desired events. This method also shows how to get the point from the event and convert it to the correct coordinate system.

Note that `self` in this code is the hosting view, not the plot space:

```
CGPoint pointOfTouch = [[[event touchesForView:self] anyObject] locationInView:self];
if ( !collapsesLayers ) {
    pointOfTouch = [self.layer convertPoint:pointOfTouch toLayer:hostedGraph];
}
else {
    pointOfTouch.y = self.frame.size.height - pointOfTouch.y;
}
```